ANT Landscape and VDM brush problem
I was experimenting with creating a noise brush for sculpting by using ANT Landscape and VDM brush together, manually unwrapping the plane. My first attempt was a success, and I managed to create a nice, smooth noise brush that worked perfectly. However, in subsequent attempts, I keep encountering the same problem: a destructive twisting effect.The problem surely comes from the EXR file that VDM brush creates, and it always comes out looking like this. Do you have any idea what causes it? Thanks in advance. 

It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.
